# Postfix - How to accept mail where DNS is not configured properly

Tags: email, postfix-mta

I have a Postfix/Dovecot server that is currently rejecting mail where DNS is not configured properly.  The sender is getting:

```
550 5.7.1 Client host rejected: cannot find your hostname
```

I'm well-aware of the 'spammy' implications, but can someone point me to a resource on where I could figure out how to disable this setting?

I can't seem to locate how to turn it off, and maybe some of you great people here will have an idea.

Thanks

Comment: Why did you down-vote me for simply asking for a little help locating a resource?  I ended up finding my own answer and posted it below, but to just go around down-voting people with legitimate questions is pretty crappy don't you think?

Comment: It wasn't me, but likely because the question is off topic on Stack Overflow. Read the [FAQ] on what's on topic here.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it.  This seems to be the setting I'm looking for:
http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_unknown_client_hostname

disable 'reject_unknown_client_hostname'  within  /etc/postix/main.cf